# innodb_thread_concurrency seems evil as it enlarge table size by big factor

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

**Environment:** OS: MS Windows 2012 R2, CPU: Xeon **12** logical processors, HDD Block Size: 8 KB, DB engine (MariaDB 10.1.23 Or MariaDB 10.2.6 Or MySQL 5.7.18) with **Default Settings**.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `z` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `testId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`testId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

1. Use below mysqlslap to make 1 Million records without concurrency (single thread, single connection) :

> mysqlslap -pPutPASS --create-schema=z --number-of-queries=1000000
>   --query="insert into test values(null)"

test.ibd size: **36.0 MB** (37,748,736 bytes)

2. Truncate/empty the table and perform concurrency insert as below:

> mysqlslap -pPutPASS --create-schema=z --concurrency=100
>   --number-of-queries=1000000 --query="insert into test values(null)" --commit=10000

test.ibd size: **56.0 MB** (58,720,256 bytes)

3. Set **innodb_thread_concurrency=12** and repeat step 2:

test.ibd size: **76.0 MB** (79,691,776 bytes) and sometimes 72 MB. *also I tested with --concurrency=500 and table size became 88.0 MB*

4. the actual optimized size is **28 MB** by using:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE `z`.`test`;

### Update 1:

Above test.ibd size results valid for MariaDB 10.1.23.

For **MariaDB 10.2.6** test.ibd size:

1. 36 MB (without concurrency)
2. 88 MB (concurrency insert with innodb_thread_concurrency=0)
3. 92 MB (innodb_thread_concurrency=12)
4. 40 MB (optimized)

For **MySQL 5.7.18** test.ibd size:

1. 36 MB (without concurrency)
2. 68 MB (concurrency insert with innodb_thread_concurrency=0)
3. 72 MB (innodb_thread_concurrency=12)
4. 40 MB (optimized)

The difference of 10.2.6 & 5.7.18 from 10.1.23 mostly due to barracuda "innodb_file_format" which seems worst than the old format as above tests shows!

## Questions:

1. Why InnoDB table size increased by big factor when I use concurrent Insertion?
2. Why innodb_thread_concurrency causing the table size to be tripled and nothing mentioned in official docs regarding that?!
3. What are the config tweaks that make MariaDB/MySQL benefit from the concurrency performance boost WHILE keeping the table size smallest? I am planning to use innodb_thread_concurrency=0 as explained in [Hyperthreading & MySQL InnoDB Thread Concurrency Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81204/hyperthreading-mysql-innodb-thread-concurrency-performance) but that's not enough, my project will have billions of records and keeping the table size as small as possible will be **big gain for performance and saving of H/W resources**.

### Update 2:

Until I get an answer for the above questions, I will highlight my project requirements in order to get best configuration:

Production Environment:

OS:  MS Windows 2012 R2

SDD: HPE 1.92TB SATA 6G Mixed, Block Size 4 KB

RAM: 768 GB

CPU: 4 Xeon Processors (Sockets) E7-8890 V3 2.5 GHZ (total cores: 72, total logical processors: 144)

Data: 150 inserts per second, 24X7, from 50 to 150 connections, single-row inserted. Avalibilty of data is 1 year (mean any record older than 1 year will be deleted), no updates on the rows, just insert once, then selecting/querying through web UI), one year data estimated to be 3-4 Billion rows. DB schema consist of one big table and 10 tables holding metadata (ex: country, etc), biggest metadata table will hold maximum of 3000 rows during the whole project life cycle. so the main focus is the big table.

So far I adjusted below config params:

```
max_connections=501
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_flush_method=async_unbuffered
innodb_flush_neighbors=0
innodb_io_capacity=400
innodb_io_capacity_max=2000
innodb_log_compressed_pages=off
innodb_write_io_threads = 12
innodb_doublewrite = off
innodb_read_io_threads = 12
skip_name_resolve=ON
# dump/restore buffer pool, faster buffer pool warmup
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  = ON
innodb_page_size=4k
```

**Please Suggest (with Explanation) further config tweaks I need in order to get the best of InnoDB and MariaDB 10.2.6**

Answer (score 3):

I suspect I will get down-voted for this Answer, but I think these things need to be said.  (And, no, I don't know the *specific* reasons for the strange sizes.)

Two simplified replies:

- InnoDB plays a lot of games in its attempts to trade off speed and space.
- Benchmarks rarely reflect anything in the real world.

Some factors (including possible explanations):

- When there are multiple inserts into one table, InnoDB takes effort to minimize the impact of one insert on the other -- this *may* involve premature block splits, duplication of rows awaiting commits, MVCC, etc.
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a bit tricky.  Your benchmark is relatively simpleminded.  In real life, there might be "burned" ids, leading to gaps in the values.  This is (I assume) a deliberate efficiency measure -- gain speed, but waste ids.  Note that there are various AI modes (see [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes)).
- BTrees are inherently sloppy.  When a block is "split", it becomes two half-full blocks.  In the single-threaded benchmark this is not a big issue since there is no contention for the 'last' block.  And InnoDB has some optimizations for such.
- BTrees are even more sloppy in the presence of MVCC -- since multiple copies of a row live for some time.
- BTree blocks (in InnoDB) are not necessarily recombined promptly.
- Allocation in in pages, extents, segments.  See [*here*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-space.html) .  This can lead to megabytes of un-recouped space.  Furthermore, there is no 'visibility' into how much space is wasted at page/extent/segment level.
- Concurrency of 100 (especially with only 12 processors) is asking for a lot of thrashing of locks in InnoDB.  Oracle, even with 5.7, does not brag above about 64.  I find that 100 leads to InnoDB stumbling over itself, and not necessarily *finishing the benchmark any sooner* than with a smaller number.  That is, excessive currency can lead to terrible latency without necessarily helping throughput.
- 10K rows may lead to an excessive use of the undo buffer (etc), thereby actually be slower than committing sooner.
- Your "project will have billions of records" -- but how fast will they be inserted, and from how many different connections, and will they be batched or single-row inserted, etc.?
- My take on [*high speed ingestion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) .

**More** (after Update 2)

- `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16`
- `innodb_doublewrite = off`  -- this may be safe since the drive and the page_size are the same.
- SSDs make 150 individual inserts/sec not a problem
- `innodb_page_size=4k` -- be aware that all tables will have to live with this.  It limits rows to under 2KB.  BTrees will be a little deeper, but I don't see that as a problem.
- With the "delete after a year", I strongly recommend using `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` with 14 (monthly) or 55 (weekly) partitions.  This will make the deletes have essentially no impact.  A `DELETE`, even daily, would probably cause hiccups.  More discussion [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) .
- How fast did the mysqlslap run (inserts/sec)?  Probably a lot faster than 150.  If your 150 is reasonably steady, then you will not experience concurrency=100, possibly rarely =10.  I don't see a problem ingesting *your* data.
- If you need to 'normalize' (ex: country, etc) the data as you load it, see my ingestion link.
- What are the `SELECTs` like?  They will be competing with the `INSERTs`.  I suspect 200 selects/sec, *if they are point queries*, could coexist with the inserts.  If you expect 1000, we need to think further.
- With partitioning, if the excessive size persists, here is a fix...  `REORGANIZE` or `REBUILD`, *not `OPTIMIZE`*, a weekly partition after it is fully built.  That way, the excessive disk usage can be freed.  Be sure to use `innodb_file_per_table` before creating the table.

Comment: The bigger the innodb_page_size (or really key_block_size), the bigger the buffer pool needs to be. Please see my post and Morgan Tocker's on this : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/innodb-file-format-barracuda/14287#14287

Comment: Toker's link talks mostly about compression, not block size.  I have a lot of negative opinions about InnoDB compression (for a different talk).