# Query about MySQL Semaphores in Engine Status

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

During a recent problem / slow down with one of our slave databases I noticed that when I ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. I am getting the following:

```
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 822986039, signal count 17045541908
--Thread 140562108442368 has waited at row0sel.c line 2930 for 0.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0x7fd752e55c40 created in file buf0buf.c line 938
a writer (thread id 140562088974080) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file row0sel.c line 2930
Last time write locked in file /tmp/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.44/storage/innobase/buf/buf0buf.c line 3168
```

In fact, there are about 15 instances of this.

Looking at the transactions there are apx 200 transactions listed, of which there are apx half showing as `waiting in InnoDB queue`, and the other half are `fetching data`.

All the transactions are `SELECT` queries, and none of them are showing any `locks`.

Can anyone tell me what the `SEMAPHORES` (above) relate to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semaphores have to do with waiting for internal thread locks in the OS

You can find a nice discussion in [**Peter Zaitsev's SHOW INNODB STATUS walk through**](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/)

The way I see it, this is related to two things

- [innodb_concurrency_tickets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets)
- [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency)

My guess is that you set [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) to a nonzero number. This causes the InnoDB storage engine to throttle its use of internal threads. Consequently, this will cause transactions to go sit in the queue.

Way back in 2011, I wrote posts about this

- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670)
- `Aug 16, 2011` : [Why do MySQL threads often show "freeing items" status when the query cache is disabled?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/905/why-do-mysql-threads-often-show-freeing-items-status-when-the-query-cache-is-d/4677#4677)
- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)

I went to Percona Live NYC in 2011. Ronald Bradford told me during a workshop to leave [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) at zero(0). Why ?

As I [mentioned in the Aug 16, 2011 post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/905/why-do-mysql-threads-often-show-freeing-items-status-when-the-query-cache-is-d/4677#4677):

> He plainly told me that I should never set values against innodb_thread_concurrency. Let it always be the default value, which is now zero(0). By doing so, you let the InnoDB storage decide how many innodb_concurrency_tickets to generate on its own. This is what infinite concurrency does.

If you have [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) as a nonzero value, please set it to 0 or remove it from `my.cnf`. Please note that [MySQL 5.6 allows for 5000 tickets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets) while [MySQL 5.5 only allows 500](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets).

If you want to change these values, you can do so dynamically with

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_thread_concurrency = 0;
```

I would recommend not setting [innodb_concurrency_tickets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets) at all.

I would also recommend reading [**Pythian's ONCE AGAIN ABOUT INNODB-CONCURRENCY-TICKETS**](http://www.pythian.com/blog/once-again-about-innodb-concurrency-tickets/)